# Android. Find view by tag

Tags: android, view, tags, find

I have a dynamically created View and want to find it by tag, is this possible?
I know the function `findViewById`, is there something similar for tags?

Comment: yes, there is findViewWithTag

Comment: Of course, you should set tag for your view first :D

Answer (score 24):

```
LinearLayout linLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewWithTag("layout1");
```

but I don't think you need tag for dynamic view. You can retrieve dynamic resource by following code

```
for (int i=0; i < total_resource; i++) {
  //retrieve id dynamically
  int id = getResources().getIdentifier("resource"+i, "id", getPackageName());
  TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(id); // get the element
}
```

Comment: You don't need it but it's extremely handy for dinamycally generated views that are to be updated from external services

Answer (score 2):

Create ids.xml to store your id:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <resources> <item type="id" name="component1" /> <item type="id" name="component2" /> <item type="id" name="component3" /> </resources>
```

Set to dynamically created component like:

```
Button1.setId(R.id.layout1); buttom2.setId(R.id.layout2); button3.setId(R.id.layout3);
```

Another way is to set a tag to your component while creating dynamically

```
button1.setTag(1);
```

And use `getTag()` to get that component

Answer (score 2):

You can find by tag inside other view.

Say, you have LinearLayout with several buttons that you dynamically put inside it and assigned tag for each of them. You MUST know id for that LinearLayout b/c 1st your find it by id. Then find buttons by tag inside that LinearLayout view:

```
LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mylinearlayout);
Button btn= (Button)ll.findViewWithTag("mybtntag");//tag must be string
```